# Magento on kubernetes, unable to run post installation script

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I am trying to deploy Magento on kubernetes, it works with the basic setup but if want to use post setup script below is the one

```
### INSTALL MAGENTO ###
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/magento
php bin/magento setup:install \
    --admin-firstname=Magento \
    --admin-lastname=Admin \
    --admin-email=admin.magento@gmail.com \
    --admin-user=admin \
    --admin-password='SomePassword123' \
    --base-url=http://148.251.11.4:8080 \
    --backend-frontname=admin \
    --db-host=mysql:3306 \
    --db-name=magento \
    --db-user=root \
    --db-password=keepitsecret \
    --use-rewrites=1 \
    --language=en_US \
    --currency=USD \
    --session-save=redis \
    --session-save-redis-host=redis \
    --session-save-redis-port=6379 \
    --session-save-redis-persistent-id=db0 \
    --cache-backend=redis \
    --cache-backend-redis-server=redis \
    --cache-backend-redis-port=6379 \
    --cache-backend-redis-db=db1 \
    --search-engine=elasticsearch7 \
    --elasticsearch-host=elasticsearch \
    --elasticsearch-port=9200 \
    --elasticsearch-enable-auth=1 \
    --elasticsearch-username=elastic \
    --elasticsearch-password=keepitsecret \
    --amqp-host=rabbitmq \
    --amqp-port=5672 \
    --amqp-user=guest \
    --amqp-password='guest' \
    --amqp-virtualhost='/'
```

I was using configmap, by mounting the volume it works for a while again the pod restarts and again it will start running the above script, below the deployment manifest file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template: 
    metadata: 
      name: frontend e
      labels: 
        app: frontend      
spec:
  containers:
    - name: magento-setup
    command: ["/mag/magentoinstaller.sh"]
    image:magentonew
  ports:
 - containerPort: 8080
 - containerPort: 9000

 volumeMounts:
 - name: magento-setup
 mountPath: /mag
             

            
volumes:
- name: magento-setup
configMap:
name: magento-setup-cm
defaultMode: 0777
```

am I using the correct way to install post-deployment script

Comment: Please [edit] to provide more details about your setup and goal. What is the script supposed to do? How is the script related to the configmap..? What does "*I used configmaps*" mean? Because you cannot run a script from a configmap. This "*which restarts the pods again and gain*" is possibly a sign of an error..? Have you checked the pod events? Either something from the pod or the script is causing an error and causing a restart. How is Magento related to this? There are so many missing info..

Comment: I agree that this question needs details, but: "Because you cannot run a script from a configmap." Sure you can; you mount it as a volume in your Pod and then each key is exposed as a file, allowing you to embed scripts in the configmap and run them in the pod.